# Deciding whether a test is a Unit or Integration test

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, integration-testing

So I'm trying to decide the way to plan and organize a testing suite for my python project but I have a doubt of when a unit test is no longer a unit test and I would love to have some feedback from the comunity.

If I understand correctly:

- A **Unit test** test a minimal part of your code, be if a function/method that does one **and only one** simple thing, even if it has several use cases.
- An **Integration test** tests that two or more units of you code that are executed under the same context, environment, etc (but trying to keep it to a minimmum of units per integration test) work well together and not only by themselves.

My doubt is: say I have a simple function that performs a HTTP request and returns the content of such request, be it HTML, JSON, etc, it doesn't matter, the fact is that the function is very, very simple but requests information from an external source, like:

```
import requests

def my_function(arg):
    # do something very simple with `arg`, like removing spaces or the simplest thing you can imagine
    return requests.get('http://www.google.com/' + arg).content
```

Now this is a very stupid example, but my doubt is:

Given that this function is requesting information from an external source, when you write a test for it, can you still consider such test a **Unit test**?

**UPDATE**: The test for `my_function()` would stub out calls to the external source so that it doesn't depend on network/db/filesystem/etc so that it's isolated. But the fact that the function that is being tested depends on external sources when running, for example, in production.

Thanks in advance!! :)

*P.S.*: Of course Maybe I'm not understading 100% de purposes of Unit and Integration testing, so, if I'm mistaken, please point me out where, I'll appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Based on your update:**

> The test for my_function() would stub out calls to the external source
>   so that it doesn't depend on network/db/filesystem/etc so that it's
>   isolated. But the fact that the function that is being tested depends
>   on external sources when running, for example, in production.

As long as the external dependencies are stubbed out during your test then yes you can call it a Unit Test. It's a Unit Test based on how the unit under test behaves in your test suite rather than how the unit behaves in production.

**Based on your original question:**

> Given that this function is requesting information from an external
>   source, when you write a test for it, can you still consider such test
>   a Unit test?

No, any test for code that touches or depends on things external to the unit under test is an integration test. This includes the existence of any web, file system, and database requests.

If your code is not 100% isolated from it's dependencies and not 100% reproducible without other components then it is an integration test.

For your example code to be properly unit tested you would need to mock out the call to google.com.

With the code calling google.com, your test would fail if google went down or you lost connection to the internet (ie the test is not 100% isolated). Your test would also fail if the behavior of google changed (ie the test is not 100% reproducable).

Comment: Hey @mezoid thanks for you answer. I'm sorry I didn't explain well enough. The function depends on external an source, but the test will definitely stub that dependency out. I'll update my question :)

Comment: @Gerard Not a problem. I've updated my answer based on your updated question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is an integration test since it doesn't make use of different parts of your application. The function does really one thing and tests for it can be called `unit`.

On the other side, this particular function has an external dependency and you don't want to be dependent on the network in your tests. This is where [`mocking`](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/) would really help a lot.

In other words, isolate the function and make `unit` tests for it.

Also, make integration tests that would use a more high-level approach and would test parts of your application which call `my_function()`.

Comment: I would have thought that any test for code that has external dependencies that have not been mocked would be an integration test..

Comment: @mezoid I see what you mean, but the "line" is really thick here. I'm saying here is that you need to isolate the `my_function()` to be sure these are unit tests. And, the tests that would be made for the `my_function()` callers would be called integration. Thank you!

Comment: Yep. I see what you are getting at.

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for the info, and I'm sorry I lacked of info. Of course I would stub out external resources with mock and similar libraries. I'll update my question :) sorry

Comment: @Gerard good, but the answer I've provided is still relevant. Take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Whether or not your code is tested in isolation is not a distinguishing criterion whether your test is a unit test or not.  For example, you would (except in very rare cases) not stub standard library functions like sin(x).  But, if you don't stub sin(x) that does not make your test an integration test.

When is a test an integration test?  A test is an integration test if your goal with the test is to find bugs on integration level.  That means, with an integration test you want to find out whether the interaction between two (or more) components is based on the same assumptions on both (all) sides.

Mocking, however, is an orthogonal technique that can be combined with almost all kinds of tests.  (In an integration test, however, you can not mock the partners of the interaction of which you want to test - but you can mock additional components).

Since mocking typically causes some effort, it must bring a benefit, like:

- significantly speeding up your tests
- testing although some software part is not ready yet or buggy
- testing exceptional cases that are hard to set up in an integrated software
- getting rid of nondeterministic behaviour like timing or randomness
- ...

If, however,  mocking does not solve a real problem, you might be better off using the depended-on component directly.